# C# Cast The Uncastable

Tags: c#

Guys I would like to know is there any possibility to do something like this:

```
class A
{
  prop T1

  prop T2

  prop T3

  prop T4
}

class B : A
{
  prop T5
}
```

And then to cast A to B.

```
A a = new A();
B b = a;
```

Maybe there is some kinda static converter class for such things so then the code might look like this.

```
A a = new A();
B b = null;
UltimativeCaster.BaseclassCast(a, b);
```

I apologize in case this is a duplicate question. I hope you guys can provide me with some ideas or solutions or some links.

EDIT: Any algorithm that finds all properties and copy past the values. Since its base class the properties will match.

Comment: No, there is no way you can do that, EVER!

Comment: Any algorithm that finds all properties and copy past the values. Since its base class the properties will match.

Comment: can you explain, Casting a parent to a child is of what use?

Comment: You should rethink your design if this is your requirement. Can you detail the requirement for us? What do you expect `b.T5` to do in this scenario (if it was possible)?

Comment: I guess you should look again at your general structure if you would want to do something like this. In the concept of inheritance, `B` is an `A`, but `A` is not necessarily a `B`. As a `Car` is a `Vehicle`, but a `Vehicle` not always a `Car`.

Comment: You can use AutoMapper as your `UltimativeCaster` here. (to create a `B` and copy all `A` property values)

Comment: You can only do this int the other way. But you can for example make a constructor for B, which takes A, set parameters from A and then sets bonus property for a default value.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I have many properties and I want to save writing alot of property mappings.

Comment: @MartinSmith That sounds interesting. I will check that out.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog - I just mention it as an option. If all you want to do is one example `A` to `B` it would likely be overkill.

Comment: @Chips_100 I know generally said that Vehicle is not always a car but at some point in your code you have to specify anyways that a car is vehicle or that this vehicle is a car.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to "cast" *a* to *b* since A is a superclass of B. I think you might be interested in something like:

```
public B CreateB(A a)
{
   B b = new B();
   b.T1 = a.T1;
   b.T2 = a.T2;
   b.T3 = a.T3;
   b.T4 = a.T4;
   return b;
}
```

By the way, you might also be interested in an automatic mapper library which does the work for you like https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper

Comment: I have many properties and I wanted to save me work of mapping each of them.

Comment: Automapper is not from Microsoft libraries right? I cant use that. It has to be Microsoft. I would need source code then I guess.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog - The link in this answer is to the source code.

Comment: Thanks I didnt see it in first place. I will mark this question as the answer.

Comment: @ninjahedgehog yes, Automapper is an open-source library for .NET, not maintained by Microsoft. But Microsoft kind of encourages using packages, since they maintain Nuget ( http://www.nuget.org/ ). Are you sure you can't use it?

Comment: I am working now on a project where I may not use third party dll. And I felt too lazzy to write down each mapping manually. Automapper will save the day. Plus its reuseable.

Answer (score 7):

In c#, an object's type cannot be changed once it's been created.

If you want to copy object A's properties to object B, you can use reflection with the following generic algorithm:

```
    public B Convert<A, B>(A element) where B : A, new()
    {
        //get the interface's properties that implement both a getter and a setter
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(A)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(property => property.CanRead && property.CanWrite).ToList();

        //create new object
        B b = new B();

        //copy the property values to the new object
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            //read value
            object value = property.GetValue(element);

            //set value
            property.SetValue(b, value);
        }

        return b;
    }
```

Comment: A bit old, but always true [T is not a base class of S, and S is not a base class of T.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664464(v=VS.71).aspx)

Comment: I like this just I may not change my entity class to write an operator and I would also like to use already some algorithm instead of mapping each property manually. I have many properties.

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast from A to B, but maybe you can use a specific constructor like

```
public B(A a)
{
    this.T1 = a.T1;
    this.T2 = a.T2;
    ...
    this.T5 = defaultvalue;
}
```

Comment: I am looking for some kind of algorthm that saves me mapping each property manually.

Comment: Then you have to use reflection or Automapper like suggested by others (which probably uses reflection).

Comment: I cant use that because its not microsoft. I would need either source code from automapper because I only may use microsoft libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this more often, and with different types, you could consider creating a factory class, creating you instances from different kind of sources:

```
public static class BFactory
{
    public static B CreateFromA(A a)
    {
        B result = new B();

        result.T1 = a.T1;
        result.T2 = a.T2;
        result.T3 = a.T3;
        result.T4 = a.T4;
        result.T5 = 0;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of factory but I would like to avoid mapping each property manually. I have many properties.

Answer (score 0):

You will  never be able to do this.  The use of polymorphism to represent one one type as another requires an "IS A" relationship between the two types. Because `A` is NOT a `B` this will never work.

Comment: As you can read in my question title I would like to cast the uncastable. So there might be some workarounds.